# Change python path in venv in windows 10 powershell?

Tags: python, windows, powershell, python-venv

I was required to downgrade my Python version. Now I get the error: `"No Python at '"C:\Python311\python.exe'"`

I found the export command is used on Linux, but there was on working answer for Windows. The current questions on SO answer similar questions and do not have working solutions for this problem.

I cannot test this, right now. This might work:

I think I need to edit `.\venv\Scripts\activate.ps1` (as by notepad++) and change the line starting with `VIRTUAL_ENV` from  `$env:VIRTUAL_ENV_PYTHON = $env:VIRTUAL_ENV + "\python.exe"` to `$env:VIRTUAL_ENV_PYTHON = "path\to\pyversion\python.exe"`

Then run `.\venv2\Scripts\Activate.ps1`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the question is precise enough, so here is a non-exhaustive tentative answer.
Did you try to activate the venv by executing :

```
venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Comment: The issue was a system issue that required restart. Not sure how or why: restarting shell after changing path did not solve the problem but restarting the computer did.